# PHP Insert New Row After Every 4th Image

Tags: php

I'm building a section that displays the most recent image in a given directory.

There are a total of 7 current directories(more to be added later so this number will vary).

I have a working code that pulls the most recent image in a directory which I've turned into a function (`displayRecent($directory);`).

I've built a `foreach` loop that runs that function for each directory in an array.

EDIT: I just noticed I didn't clarify one thing. Inside of every `<div class="row">` I want to have a maximum of 4 `<div class="col-md-3">`.

So if there are 9 directories then there would be a total of 3 `<div class="row">` while the last one only contains one `<div class="col-md-3">`.

What I'm hoping to accomplish is the following mark-up:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3"> 
  <img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth/5361af753f447.jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
 </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> 
  <img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth/5361af753f447.jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
 </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> 
  <img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth/5361af753f447.jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
 </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> 
  <img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth/5361af753f447.jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-3"> 
  <img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth/5361af753f447.jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
 </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> 
  <img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth/5361af753f447.jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
 </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> 
  <img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth/5361af753f447.jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
 </div>
<div class="col-md-3"> 
  <img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth/5361af753f447.jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
 </div>
</div>
```

But instead my code is only wrapping the fourth directory with `<div class="row">` and `</div>`

The actual output is:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/nude//5361b0351fcb4.jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
$directories = array("goth", "nude", "goth", "goth", "goth", "goth", "goth", "goth", "goth"); 

$i = 0;

foreach ($directories as $directory) {
 if($i == 4) {
  echo '<div class="row">' . "\r\n";
 }
    echo '<div class="col-md-3">' . "\r\n";
    displayRecent($directory);
    echo '</div>' . "\r\n";
 if($i == 4) {
  echo '</div>' . "\r\n";
 }
 $i++;
}
```

And the contents of the `displayRecent($directory)` function just in case it's relevant or can be built upon:

```
function displayRecent($recentDir) {
$dir = 'gallery/'.$recentDir . '/';
$base_url = 'http://example.com/gallery/'.$recentDir.'/';
$newest_mtime = 0;
$show_file = 'BROKEN';
if ($handle = opendir($dir)) {
while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
if (($file != '.') && ($file != '..')) {
$mtime = filemtime("$dir/$file");
if ($mtime > $newest_mtime) {
$newest_mtime = $mtime;
$show_file = "$base_url/$file";
}
}
}
}
echo '<img src="' .$show_file. '" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">' . "\r\n";
}
```

**EDIT**

Changing the `foreach` loop to the following results in the following output:

```
$directories = array("goth", "nude", "goth", "goth", "goth", "goth", "goth", "goth", "goth"); 

$i = 0;

foreach ($directories as $directory) {
 if( !($i % 4) ) {
  echo '<div class="row">' . "\r\n";
 }
    echo '<div class="col-md-3">' . "\r\n";
    displayRecent($directory);
    echo '</div>' . "\r\n";
 if( !($i % 4) ) {
  echo '</div>' . "\r\n";
 }
 $i++;
}
```

Output - For some reason the first `col-md-3` is in it's own `row` when there should be three more `col-md-3` inside of that same `row` element:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/nude//5361b0351fcb4.jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
<img src="http://example.com/gallery/goth//5361af753f447 (1).jpg" alt="Image Title Here" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</div>
</div>
```

**NOTE** The reason I have the same directory listed several times in the array is because all of the directories are not yet built so I am repeating one for testing purposes.

**NOTE 2** Just because I know some joker may ask, no this is not a pornographic website it's merely a modeling website. :)

Comment: if ( !($i % 4) ) echo 'your separator';

Comment: It's working for the most part. For some reason the very first `<div class="col-md-4">` is in its own row when it should have 3 more with it. See my updated question for the new output with your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just explain and improve my answer in my comment.

This is *.phtml syntax:

```
<div class="row"> <!-- open first row -->
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    <?php foreach ($directories as $directory) { ?>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <?php displayRecent($directory); ?>
        </div>
        <?php if ( !($i % 4) ) { ?>
            </div><div class="row"> <!-- close prev row, open next -->
        <?php } ?>
        <?php $i += 1; ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div> <!-- close last row -->
```